# Is it common to add comission to the contract for the secondary market?

Tags: contract-design, nft, mint

I looked at Cryptopunks contract and I don't see any royalty going to Larva Labs. Is it normal to add a comission back to me for my generative art project?

I noticed some projects take a set price when going live with minting but is that all they take?

Answer (score 1):

> I looked at Cryptopunks contract and I don't see any royalty going to Larva Labs. Is it normal to add a comission back to me for my generative art project?

Yes

> I noticed some projects take a set price when going live with minting but is that all they take?

Without you naming "some projects" and giving specifics links, any answer would be pure guess work.

Comment: The latest one I noticed is this one https://mintnftoker.cryptocannabisclub.com It's something they never say upfront so you end up looking for in their contract. I was wondering if it's a common practice. Thank you!